# extract hstore key and make it into a column in datatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, hstore

I am currently trying to build a table to display a list of users with their attributes in separate columns.
it is something like:

---

user1 | user1 email | user1 admin role | user1 organiser role

---

user2 | user2 email | user2 admin role | user2 organiser role

---

user3 | user3 email | user3 admin role | user3 organiser role

However, the admin and organiser attributes are stored in a hstore column called activities.

When I build the datatable the browser returns this error

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown
>   parameter 'activities.organiser' for row 0. For more information about
>   this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

This is my code where I build my table columns
in manage_user_controller.rb

```
 private

 def load_columns
  columns = []
  columns << {:data => "id", :title => "ID"}
  columns << {:data => "email", :title => "Email"}
  columns << {:data => "created_at", :title => "Created"}
  columns << {:data => 'activities.organiser', :title => "Organiser Role"}
  columns << {:data => 'activities.admin', :title => "Admin Role"}
  columns << {:data => "id", :title => ""}
  return columns
 end
```

in my users_datatable.rb

```
private

 def data
  results = []
  users.each_with_index do |user, index|
   cols = {"id" => "#{user.id}"}
   cols.merge!("email" => "#{user.email}")
   cols.merge!("created_at" => "#{user.created_at}")
   cols.merge!("activities" => "#{user.activities.organiser}")
   cols.merge!("activities" => "#{user.activities.admin}")
   #cols.merge!("activities" => "#{user.activities.admin_events}")
   results << cols
  end
  return results
 end
```

I have tried to change "activities.organiser" to "activities" in the controller, it will load some values, but I cant possible use activites for all the sub attributes in activites itself because that will be wrong.

So, how should I correctly populate a datatable with key-value pairs from hstore column?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i manage to solve it.

in the manage_users_controller.rb

```
 def load_columns
  columns = []
  columns << {:data => "id", :title => "ID"}
  columns << {:data => "email", :title => "Email"}
  columns << {:data => "created_at", :title => "Created"}
  columns << {:data => "organiser", :title => "Organiser Role"}
  columns << {:data => "admin", :title => "Admin Role"}
  columns << {:data => "id", :title => ""}
  return columns
 end
```

In the user_datatable.rb

```
def data
  results = []
  users.each_with_index do |user, index|
   cols = {"id" => "#{user.id}"}
   cols.merge!("email" => "#{user.email}")
   cols.merge!("created_at" => "#{user.created_at}")
   cols.merge!("organiser" => "#{user.activities.organiser}")
   cols.merge!("admin" => "#{user.activities.admin}")
   #cols.merge!("activities" => "#{user.activities.admin_events}")
   results << cols
  end
  return results
 end
```

the names must be the same in both files.